# Sequence formula for a recurrence relationship

Tags: recurrence-relations

Fix positive a, b, c. Define a sequence of real numbers by $x_0 = a$, $x_1 = b$ and $x_{n+1} = cx_nx_{n-1}$. Find formula for $x_n$.

Comment: Have you tried writing down the first few terms to see if you can spot a pattern?

Comment: well, you know that $x_n=c^{\gamma_n} a^{\alpha_n}b^{\beta_n}$, so you can derive a recurrence formula for $\alpha_n$, $\beta_n$ and $\gamma_n$

Comment: $\alpha_i = 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6...$
$\beta_i = 0 1 1 2 3 5 8$ ---> Fibinocci series
$\gamma_i = 0 0 1 2 4 7 12$

Comment: Your $\alpha_i$ are incorrect. The exponents are all closely related to the Fibonacci sequence. Perhaps it's easier to see when you consider $y_n = cx_n$.

Comment: $\alpha_i = 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6...$ ---> I can't understand this series
$\beta_i = 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8,...$ ---> Fibinocci series
$\gamma_i = 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 12,...$ I can't understand this series

Answer (score 0):

The first few terms of sequence is $a, b, cab, c^2ab^2, c^4a^2b^3, c^7a^3b^5, c^12a^5b^8 ...$

If we look at the exponents of a, b, c, we have:

$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n      & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  & 7  & 8  &       expression         \\
\hline
fib\_n & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 8  & 13 & 21 &                \\
\hline
a      & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5  & 8  & 13 & fib\_\{n-1\}   \\
\hline
b      & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 8  & 13 & 21 & fib\_n         \\
\hline
c      & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 7 & 12 & 20 & 33 & fib\_\{n+1\}-1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$

Assuming you have closed form for fib, just join everything together to get the closed form for $x_n$.